# Azure ARM Template Special Characters

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is there a way to send a string with special characters to an ARM template custom extension? Currently having an issue with only receiving a portion of the password
ex password **fkdl2#dlsj** I only see **fkdl2** of the password being sent to the shell script. The rest of the characters are being stripped off.

```
 "properties":{
   "publisher":"Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
   "type":"CustomScript",
   "typeHandlerVersion":"2.1",
   "autoUpgradeMinorVersion":true,
   "settings":{
      "skipDos2Unix":false,
      "timestamp":123456789
   },
   "protectedSettings":{
      "commandToExecute":"[concat('sh /example/dir/setup.sh ', parameters('password')]"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [base64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#base64) function when passing the argument:

```
"commandToExecute":"[concat('sh /example/dir/setup.sh ', base64(parameters('password')))]"
```

and then decode it inside the `setup.sh` script